# Is latest kernel code for arm architecture wrong at slow_work_pending?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, arm, embedded

Currently I am working with embeded Linux kernel for ARM architecture. As latest kernel source code that bootlin provided, I see these code in *arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S*:

```
slow_work_pending:
    mov r0, sp    @'regs'
    mov r2, why    @'syscall'
    bl do_work_pending
```

Do `syscall` parameter of `do_work_pending()` suppose to be `r1` ?

I have tried debug this by print that parameter while kernel is starting up. At that time `why` register should be 0, but printk said that `syscall` is -173b500.

Is those code a mistake or intentionally coded?

I presume that at kernel startup `why` should be 0 since it is not a real syscall, but printing it with printk give me weird negative number. Do my understanding of `why` wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as how the most recent upstream sources have the same code (even though the filename has been changed to replace the `_` with a `-`) then unless it's an extremely rare code path, it's probably not wrong.  Chances are you are misunderstanding what is going on here.

But let's look at the specifics

```
slow_work_pending:
    mov r0, sp    @'regs'
    mov r2, why    @'syscall'
    bl do_work_pending
```

> Do syscall parameter of do_work_pending() suppose to be r1 ?

Considering the prototype of the function found in signal.c

```
asmlinkage int
do_work_pending(struct pt_regs *regs, unsigned int thread_flags, int syscall)
```

It would look like the answer is "no" - the `syscall` is the third argument and thus should be in r2, because r1 contains `thread_flags` - and presumably already did so befor the code around `slow_work_pending` which you examined.

Comment: Ooops, I see my bad, but there is one more thing I do not understand quitely. I try to print `syscall` while the kernel is booting up; at this time I expect `syscall` should be 0 instead of weird negative number, isn't it?

Comment: It would be whatever syscall argument value is applicable to the path of execution that got to the point where you evaluated it.  Perhaps where you evaluated it or how you printed it is not even valid.  Without looking at the details it is also possible something like that might have additional bits OR'd in and not be simply a "number"